# EPPlus Excel export, how to print header column from list

Tags: c#, epplus

I want to add header column using a List.

I tried with this, but it print only first column.

```
List<string> headerColumns1 = new List<string>()
{
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
};

ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
workSheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(headerColumns, false); //
workSheet.Cells[2, 1].LoadFromCollection(data, false);
```

it prints only "1" in first column.

How can I print the all header columns in first row?

Comment: I can do this with Microsoft.Interop.Excel by using worksheets' ranges

Comment: @Forlani don't do this. On the case of server it requires installed MS Office.   EPPlus very powerful library.

Comment: @SouXin I will take a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified only one Cell
This code: `workSheet.Cells[1, 1]` shows your mistake

You have two options:
Specify the range

```
using (ExcelRange range = ec.Cells[1, 1, 1, headerColumns.Count])
{
    range.LoadFromCollection(headerColumns, false);
}
```

Or use foreach to populate manually

```
int index = 1;
foreach(var item in headerColumns)
{
    workSheet.Cells[1, index++].Value = item;
}
```

Take a look to [LoadFromCollection](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/EPPlus/EPPlus/ExcelRangeBase/M/LoadFromCollection(T))

> Load a collection into a the worksheet starting from the top left row of the range.

p.s. I believe it's just typing error: `List<string> headerColumns1 = new List<string>()` against `workSheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(headerColumns, false);`

Answer (score 0):

The function will take a collection and treat each entry as a `Row` object and uses Reflections to print each property as column values.  So if you give it that collection it sees it R1C1 = "1", R2C1 = "2", and then R3C1 = "3".

BUT, the line `workSheet.Cells[2, 1].LoadFromCollection(data, false);` it will overwrite all values from R2C1 and down because that is the top-right cell it starts in.

So, to do what you want you need to give a `List` of things with a single entry in it.  For example, this would solve the problem with your code above (but you may end up needing something more sophisticated then a `Tuple`):

```
var headerColumns = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>
{
    new Tuple<string, string, string>("1","2","3")
};

workSheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(headerColumns, false);
```

Which shows as this:

[image]